# Doctrine MongoDB Bundle: Cursor toArray() Error When "_id" is an Array

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine

Resulting from a MapReduce, I have a MongoDb collection that has the following structure:

```
{ "_id" : { "id" : NumberLong(1), "date" : "04-26-2012" }, "value" : { "count" : 100 } }
```

In my controller I am doing the following to return an array to display the results:

```
$mongoDb         = $mongo->selectDatabase($dbname);        
$mongoCollection = $mongoDb->selectCollection($collname);
$qb              = $mongoCollection->createQueryBuilder(); 
$qb              = $qb->find();        
$resultCursor    = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
                                  ->limit(10);
$resultArray     = $resultCursor  ->toArray();
```

However, I get an exception: "Notice: Array to string conversion in vendor/doctrine-mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Cursor.php line 154"

Below is line 154 of Cursor.php. Does MongoCursor::key not handle "_id" as an Array?

```
/** @proxy */
public function key()
{
    return $this->mongoCursor->key();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `_id` cannot be an array or object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

key() always returns a string (see http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), so it's generating that notice trying to convert an array into string form.  It is only a notice, though, it should still work.

The easiest way around this is probably just not to call toArray() on the cursor: iterate through it instead (`foreach $resultCursor as $value) ...`).

Comment: Thanks, Kristina. Using twig, and not calling toArray() I still get the same "notice". I'll have to see if I can make a configuration change so that I do not get the "notice".

Comment: I turned off the notice by adding the following to my code: error_reporting(0);

Answer (score 9):

For fast converting mongoDb cursor to array you may use http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->hydrate(false);

$query = $qb->getQuery();

$resultArray = iterator_to_array($query->execute());
```

Comment: This will not work as well, the "key" must be a string.